# How to group by with a condition in PySpark

Tags: sql, pyspark, count, apache-spark-sql, pivot

How to group by with a condition in PySpark?

This is an example data:

```
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+
| zip | state | Agegrouping | patient_id |
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+
| 123 | x     | Adult       |        123 |
| 124 | x     | Children    |        231 |
| 123 | x     | Children    |        456 |
| 156 | x     | Adult       |        453 |
| 124 | y     | Adult       |         34 |
| 432 | y     | Adult       |         23 |
| 234 | y     | Children    |         13 |
| 432 | z     | Children    |         22 |
| 234 | z     | Adult       |         44 |
+-----+-------+-------------+------------+
```

then wanted to see the data as:

```
+-----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| zip | state | Adult | Children | patient_id |
+-----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| 123 | x     |     1 |        1 |          2 |
| 124 | x     |     1 |        1 |          2 |
| 156 | x     |     1 |        0 |          1 |
| 432 | y     |     1 |        1 |          2 |
| 234 | z     |     1 |        1 |          2 |
+-----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: x = spark.sql("select zip,state,state_fips,count,county_fips \
              sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Adolescent' then 1 else 0 end) as Adolescent, \
              sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Pediatrics' then 1 else 0 end) as Pediatrics, \
              sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Adults' then 1 else 0 end) as Adults, \
              count(*) as patient_id \
              from pd_df_c19_patients \
              group by zip,state,state_fips,count,county_fips") and the error it was showing:  "\nmismatched input '(' expecting <EOF>(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the spark sql version.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('table')

spark.sql('''
    select zip, state,
           count(if(Agegrouping = 'Adult', 1, null)) as adult,
           count(if(Agegrouping = 'Children', 1, null)) as children,
           count(1) as patient_id
    from table
    group by zip, state;
''').show()

+---+-----+-----+--------+----------+
|zip|state|adult|children|patient_id|
+---+-----+-----+--------+----------+
|123|    x|    1|       1|         2|
|156|    x|    1|       0|         1|
|234|    z|    1|       0|         1|
|432|    z|    0|       1|         1|
|234|    y|    0|       1|         1|
|124|    y|    0|       0|         1|
|124|    x|    0|       1|         1|
|432|    y|    1|       0|         1|
+---+-----+-----+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Hiya, what's the difference between using if() as you have and `case when`? Isn't if() a hive function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select zip, state,
       sum(case when agegrouping = 'Adult' then 1 else 0 end) as adult,
       sum(case when agegrouping = 'Children' then 1 else 0 end) as children,
       count(*) as num_patients
from t
group by zip, state;
```

Comment: i tried to use the below codes and here it is: x = spark.sql("select zip,state,state_fips,count,county_fips \
              sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Adolescent' then 1 else 0 end) as Adolescent, \
              sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Pediatrics' then 1 else 0 end) as Pediatrics, \
              sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Adults' then 1 else 0 end) as Adults, \
              count(*) patient_id \
              from pd_df_c19_patients \
              group by zip,state,state_fips,count,county_fips")

Comment: here is the error  ParseException: "\nmismatched input '(' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 63)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect zip,state,state_fips,count,county_fips               sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Adolescent' then 1 else 0 end) as Adolescent,               sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Pediatrics' then 1 else 0 end) as Pediatrics,               sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Adults' then 1 else 0 end) as Adults,               count(*) patient_id               from pd_df_c19_patients               group by zip,state,state_fips,count,county_fips\n-----------

Comment: @NiranjanGrandhi . . . `count` doesn't seem like a likely name for a column.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggreagation:

```
select 
    zip,
    state,
    sum(case when agregrouping = 'Adult'    then 1 else 0 end ) as adult
    sum(case when agregrouping = 'Children' then 1 else 0 end ) as children,
    count(*) patient_id
from mytable
group by zip, state
```

Comment: Here it is: x = spark.sql("select zip,state,state_fips,count,county_fips \
              (sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Adolescent' then 1 else 0 end) as Adolescent), \
              (sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Pediatrics' then 1 else 0 end) as Pediatrics), \
              (sum(case when AgeGrouping = 'Adults' then 1 else 0 end) as Adults), \
              (count(*) as patient_id) \
              from pd_df_c19_patients \
              group by zip,state,state_fips,count,county_fips")